# what is try function in python(pyspark)

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to extract 2nd element in array
So I write this

```
spark.sql("""
          SELECT  TRY(object_url[2])
         ~~~~~
```

I write TRY function. Because sometimes there is not a second element.
But I have a  problem. TRY function isn't work in pyspark(python).
What is the similar function? umm...help me.

FYI. I always use the TRY function in AWS Athena when I extract array element.

Answer (score 0):

No need to try. It will gives you the null value when the index is out of range.

```
spark.sql('''SELECT test, test[2] from test''').show()

+------+-------+
|  test|test[2]|
+------+-------+
|[1, 2]|   null|
+------+-------+
```